# Converting the case and then joining the string

Tags: string, go, concatenation

I have a slice like this

```golang
v := []string{"this", "is", "a", "sample", "string"}
```

I want to create `ThisIsASampleString`. The only approach I could think of is first looping through the slice, convert them to title case and then join them i.e.,

```golang
x := []string{}
for _, s := range v {
    x = append(x, strings.Title(s))
}

strings.Join(x[0:], "")
```

Is there any better approch?

Answer (score 1):

Benchmark (go version go1.15.6 linux/amd64):

```
BenchmarkBuilder-8     1480506  792 ns/op  112 B/op  8 allocs/op
BenchmarkBuffer-8      1500859  843 ns/op  144 B/op  7 allocs/op
BenchmarkJoin-8        1350139  938 ns/op  160 B/op  7 allocs/op
BenchmarkReplaceAll-8  1513950  793 ns/op  128 B/op  4 allocs/op
BenchmarkLoop-8        2322938  536 ns/op  112 B/op  2 allocs/op
```

---

1. Using `strings.Builder`:

```
sb := new(strings.Builder)
for _, s := range v {
    sb.WriteString(strings.Title(s))
}
st := sb.String()
```

---

2. Using `bytes.Buffer`:

```
p := new(bytes.Buffer)
for _, s := range v {
    p.WriteString(strings.Title(s))
}
st = p.String()
```

---

3. Using `strings.Join(x, "")`:

```
x := make([]string, len(v))
for i, s := range v {
    x[i] = strings.Title(s)
}
st = strings.Join(x, "")
```

---

4. One-liner (note: no space inside input elements)

```
st = strings.ReplaceAll(strings.Title(strings.Join(v, " ")), " ", "")
```

---

5. Basic loop:

```
n := 0
for _, s := range v {
    n += len(s)
}
x := make([]rune, 0, n)
for _, s := range v {
    for i, r := range s {
        if i == 0 {
            r = unicode.ToUpper(r)
        }
        x = append(x, r)
    }
}
st = string(x)
```

---

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "strings"
    "testing"
    "unicode"
)

func BenchmarkBuilder(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        sb := new(strings.Builder)
        for _, s := range v {
            sb.WriteString(strings.Title(s))
        }
        st = sb.String()
    }
}
func BenchmarkBuffer(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        p := new(bytes.Buffer)
        for _, s := range v {
            p.WriteString(strings.Title(s))
        }
        st = p.String()
    }
}
func BenchmarkJoin(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x := make([]string, len(v))
        for i, s := range v {
            x[i] = strings.Title(s)
        }
        st = strings.Join(x, "")
    }
}
func BenchmarkReplaceAll(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        st = strings.ReplaceAll(strings.Title(strings.Join(v, " ")), " ", "")
    }
}
func BenchmarkLoop(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        n := 0
        for _, s := range v {
            n += len(s)
        }
        x := make([]rune, 0, n)
        for _, s := range v {
            for i, r := range s {
                if i == 0 {
                    r = unicode.ToUpper(r)
                }
                x = append(x, r)
            }
        }
        st = string(x)
    }
}

var v = []string{"this", "is", "a", "sample", "string"}

var st string
```

Command:

```
go test -v -bench=. -count=4 -benchmem -benchtime=1000000x
```

Output:

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
 
BenchmarkBuilder-8               1000000  809 ns/op  112 B/op  8 allocs/op
BenchmarkBuilder-8               1000000  812 ns/op  112 B/op  8 allocs/op
BenchmarkBuilder-8               1000000  753 ns/op  112 B/op  8 allocs/op
BenchmarkBuilder-8               1000000  823 ns/op  112 B/op  8 allocs/op
      
BenchmarkBuffer-8                1000000  845 ns/op  144 B/op  7 allocs/op
BenchmarkBuffer-8                1000000  768 ns/op  144 B/op  7 allocs/op
BenchmarkBuffer-8                1000000  805 ns/op  144 B/op  7 allocs/op
BenchmarkBuffer-8                1000000  811 ns/op  144 B/op  7 allocs/op
      
BenchmarkJoin-8                  1000000  930 ns/op  160 B/op  7 allocs/op
BenchmarkJoin-8                  1000000  936 ns/op  160 B/op  7 allocs/op
BenchmarkJoin-8                  1000000  896 ns/op  160 B/op  7 allocs/op
BenchmarkJoin-8                  1000000  876 ns/op  160 B/op  7 allocs/op
      
BenchmarkReplaceAll-8            1000000  793 ns/op  128 B/op  4 allocs/op
BenchmarkReplaceAll-8            1000000  759 ns/op  128 B/op  4 allocs/op
BenchmarkReplaceAll-8            1000000  765 ns/op  128 B/op  4 allocs/op
BenchmarkReplaceAll-8            1000000  781 ns/op  128 B/op  4 allocs/op
      
BenchmarkLoop-8                  1000000  535 ns/op  112 B/op  2 allocs/op
BenchmarkLoop-8                  1000000  530 ns/op  112 B/op  2 allocs/op
BenchmarkLoop-8                  1000000  506 ns/op  112 B/op  2 allocs/op
BenchmarkLoop-8                  1000000  487 ns/op  112 B/op  2 allocs/op
PASS
ok       15.250s
```

Comment: please give us your `go version`.

Comment: go version go1.15.6 linux/amd64

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the bytes.Buffer or strings.Builder to efficiently concatenate strings. Here's an example using [bytes.Buffer](https://golang.org/src/bytes/buffer.go)

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

var v = []string{"this", "is", "a", "sample", "string"}

func BenchmarkWithBuilder(b *testing.B) {
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        UsingBuilder(v)
    }
}

func BenchmarkWithBuffer(b *testing.B) {
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        UsingBuffer(v)
    }
}

// Since Go 1.10 has strings.Builder.
func UsingBuilder(v []string) string {
    var builder strings.Builder
    for _, s := range v {
        builder.WriteString(strings.Title(s))
    }
    return builder.String()
}

// pre Go 1.10 the most effective way was to use bytes.Buffer
func UsingBuffer(v []string) string {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    for _, s := range v {
        buffer.WriteString(strings.Title(s))
    }
    return buffer.String()
}
```

and here are the benchmarks results for each function.

```
$ go test -v -bench=. -count=4 -benchmem
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: test/bench
BenchmarkWithBuilder
BenchmarkWithBuilder-4       1294498           905 ns/op         112 B/op          8 allocs/op
BenchmarkWithBuilder-4       1307007           911 ns/op         112 B/op          8 allocs/op
BenchmarkWithBuilder-4       1313634           911 ns/op         112 B/op          8 allocs/op
BenchmarkWithBuilder-4       1308748           909 ns/op         112 B/op          8 allocs/op
BenchmarkWithBuffer
BenchmarkWithBuffer-4        1388026           869 ns/op         144 B/op          7 allocs/op
BenchmarkWithBuffer-4        1389976           867 ns/op         144 B/op          7 allocs/op
BenchmarkWithBuffer-4        1380103           860 ns/op         144 B/op          7 allocs/op
BenchmarkWithBuffer-4        1380252           874 ns/op         144 B/op          7 allocs/op
PASS
ok      test/bench  16.796s
$ go version
go version go1.15.2 linux/amd64
```

Comment: I, more than slightly, updated your post to provide fully reproducible benchmark. I also added -benchmem argument. And finally i added (my) go version. Benchmarking the time is interesting, but as this is a public benchmark, that no one has the same equipment, measuring time is not so interesting, having intrinsec information about the behavior (allocations) of the algorithm is more useful.

Comment: Thanks @mh-cbon that was really helpful.